# Why doesn't my array of booleans work for the Problem Ragaman from CCC?

Tags: java

The problem I am trying to solve is Senior Problem S1 (Ragaman) from the 2016 Canadian Computing Competition: https://cccgrader.com/

Paraphrased problem description and specification:

```
Given two strings of length N (1 <= N <= 100), determine whether the second 
string is a wildcard anagram of the first.  The first string will consist 
entirely of lower case letter characters, the second might also contain 
asterisk characters.
```

My code (in Java) already works for some cases but not all, and i've been trying to figure out the problem of my code for a few days and I still can't find it. I have used different array of booleans and int to solve the problem.

```
//s1_2016
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s1 = in.nextLine();
        String s2 = in.nextLine();
        String newS2 = "";
        int  c = 0;

        //create new S2 string with no *
        for(int i=0;i<s2.length();i++)
            if(s2.charAt(i)!='*')
                newS2 = newS2 + s2.charAt(i);
            else
                c++;

        //makes a array of false based on the length of s1
        Boolean[] boolS1 = new Boolean[101];
        for(int i=0;i<101;i++)
            boolS1[i]=false;

        //main algorithm
        for(int i=0;i<newS2.length();i++)
            for(int j=0;j<s1.length();j++)
            {
                if((newS2.charAt(i)==s1.charAt(j))&&(boolS1[j]==false))
                    boolS1[j]=true;
            }
        //boolean found=true;
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
            if (boolS1[i]==false)
                counter++;
        }

        if(counter==c)
            System.out.println("A");
        else 
            System.out.println("N");
    }
}
```

If the code works for both the sample problems, it would be most likely working but when I try solving it with more long numbers, that's when it should start not working. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question and add a description of the challenge instead of a link.

Comment: What tests are it failing on? What is the expected vs actual result? [It's not working is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). As Andrew says, don't make us follow links, post everything we need to help you in one place. My proxy blocks that site so I have no idea what you want to accomplish

Comment: Can you include a few sample strings where your code fails to properly output 'N' or 'A'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider sample input 2

1. `cccrocks`
2. `socc*rk*`

and walk yourself through your "main algorithm".  For each position in newS2 you are testing every position in S1 for a match. What happens when `i == 2`?

The `newS2.charAt(2)` is 'c' which will match with the `s1.charAt(0); charAt(1); charAt(2); and charAt(5)` AND the Boolean array is initialized to `false`, so positions 0, 1, 2, and 5 in the Boolean array are all updated to `true` while `i == 2`.  That's not the behavior you want for finding anagrams.

You need to break out of the inner loop after finding your first match and setting that Boolean index to `true`.  Your solution may still have other problems, but I think that's the main one.